# How to toggle specific divs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

Okay so I have a very limited amount of knowledge with this and I can not find my answer anywhere. What I am trying to do is create multiple buttons that toggle information. So when the first toggle is clicked div 1 is toggled, when i click the second toggle div two opens and preferably div 1 closes. My code is very basic I am very new to this. Right now no matter what values I input into the toggle area both divs close. Thank you and I hope this makes sense.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div.house").toggle();

  });
});
</script>

<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="house">
<p>SAMPLE TEXT ETC...</p>
</div>

<button>Toggle</button>
<div class="tumble-by">
<p>SAMPLE TEXT ETC...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the next sibling:

```
$("button").click(function(){
   $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

In the above code, JavaScript [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword refers to the clicked element. `$(this)` creates a jQuery collection and [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method selects the very next sibling of the collection's element.

Comment: You are amazing haha this worked perfectly. I have one more question if you could help. Is there a way to make them all hidden until clicked? Instead of starting open. This was so simple thank you again.

Comment: @Vincent You are very welcome. You can add a common class to the target `div` elements and then hide them using `.hide()` method. `$('.targetDivs').hide()`. Yes, jQuery makes DOM manipulation so simple. You just need to learn the basics of it and done, there is no next step.

Comment: I have another question sorry... Is there a way to replace the toggle button with an image? So I have an image that is 200x50 px and I want that to be the toggle button instead of the grey "toggle". Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Vincent Yes, just replace the `button` element with an `img` element. Add a class name to it, `.button_img` as an exmaple, and replace the `button` selector with `img.button_img`. You can also use a different element like `span` and sets it's `background-image` property by using your image path.

Comment: Sadly I am not entirely sure what you mean by this. But the span option using the background-img and my path sounds like it would work. Would this be applied to the <button>?

Answer (score 0):

I agree too, that first you need to hide all divs:

```
$("button").click(function () {
    $('div').hide();
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", ".js-toggle__button", function (e) {
            $(".js-toggle__text").hide();
            $(this).next(".js-toggle__text").show();
        });
    });
</script>

<button class="toggle__button js-toggle__button">Toggle</button>
<div class="toggle__text js-toggle__text">
    <p>SAMPLE TEXT 1 ETC...</p>
</div>

<button class="toggle__button js-toggle__button">Toggle</button>
<div class="toggle__text js-toggle__text">
    <p>SAMPLE TEXT 2 ETC...</p>
</div>
```

It's better to use uniquely defined identifiers when you accessing elements from JS (and don't use them for CSS — use separate names).

Your HTML code some day can be changed dramatically and JS will work anyway because it depends on identifiers but not on structure or on tag names.